# ArgumentException was unhandled. Как это исправить?

Tags: c#, sqlite

Создаю приложение с SQLite. Добавил библиотеку - System.Data.SQLite, но она не сработала. Вывела ошибку о несовместимости версии библиотеки с версией .Net. Добавил в App.Config file следующее:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Прокатило. Но вывела вот следующее:

> Не удалось найти запрошенного поставщика данных .Net Framework. Возможно он не установлен.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Попробуй в свойствах проекта явно указать тип программы: x86 или x64

Comment: Думаешь от этого? Он же вроде другое просит :/ @petya

Comment: Ну попробовать-то ты можешь или нет?

Comment: то же самое выводит. Не прокатило @petya

Answer (score 3):

Добавляйте SQLite в проект при помощи NuGet и будет вам счастье! Там имеется под нужную версию фреймворка и сразу обе версии: х86 и х64. Установка и гак не нужен вообще.

Comment: Гы гы гы !

Comment: аргументы?

Comment: Не, не всё прикольно. Просто утверждение насчёт Гак... И сторонний хелпер для зависимостей... Конечно, зачем нам знать истоки, если есть какая-то утилитка которая сделает это за нас. А если что не работает - можно на хеше спросить... Там наверняка найдётся человек который напишет непонятный код за нас :-D

Comment: Данный подход реально удобный и имеет ряд преимуществ!

Comment: Не спорю, удобная штука, при большом количестве сторонних библиотек. Можно наверное даже настроить на внутреннее использование при динамичном развитии компонентов системы. Но... это будет мега гемор для QA... В серьёзных проектах, имхо, это будет постоянным стрессом. А для опен сорс и быстрой или внутренней разработки - да, очень удобно.

Comment: Не очень понял про проблему куа и в чем стресс?

Comment: В обновлении пакетов. Стресс в том что если пакет прибили/обновили, и у одного разработчика одна версия, у другого или не ставиться (если залочено) или ставиться другая версия, а баг был завязан на конкретную версию и придётся или всё опять перетестировать ну или что ещё... Вобщем... стресс

Comment: Да ну - за продолжительное время использования не было никогда особого стресса. У всех всегда одинаковая версия зависимостей. Если кто-то обновил\убил пакет, то после заливки в репозиторий и обновления у команды, версии снова становятся одинаковыми. Иногда бывает каша внутри пакетов в кроссзависомостями, но это единичные случаи. К тому же всегда можно откатиться и тд. В общем, как по мне - надуманная проблема.

Answer (score 0):

А Вы уверены что поставили нужную версию sqlite?
[тут можно посмотреть какие есть для дот нета](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

Comment: Поставили??? А это как? Ну т.е я всего лишь прикрепил библиотеку System.Data.SQLite. Что то еще нужно разве? А у вас есть данная библиотека для .Net4? @Чад

Comment: А Вы по ссылочке пройдитесь. Setups for 32-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0) и Setups for 64-bit Windows (.NET Framework 4.0)

Comment: Можно конечно и просто прикрепить, но надо нужную версию dll взять. Вы скорее всего взяли не для .net 4.x а для 3.x. Установка просто поставит в GAG Sqlite